# Image Buttons Xml and Activity Error for tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, imagebutton

Sorry for english
First this is the main screen on my application:

[image: Main]

ok, so im creating a wallpaper application for android and when i have my xml file in this way with the image buttons:
[image: Unerrored Verison]

It works completely fine.

But when i have in this format for tablets:
[image: error Verison]

This version when i go back to home screen and select a diffrent category i get Force Close and i dont know why, with the first version it doesnt Force close but the other layout does? i dont under stand it could some one help me.
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Where's the logcat? Where's the code? :)

Comment: I think their something wrong with the xml not java

Comment: Does anyone have another idea for a layout for imagebuttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the error for some reason android doesnt like the layout format that way had to change it, thanks anyways everybody